# Compile error: j is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])

Tags: java

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
class Looping {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        long j;
        for (int i = 0, j = 3; i <= 10; i++, j++) {
            System.out.println(j);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following compile error:

> j is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])

The error occurred at the line with the `for` loop. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 6):

You are in effect declaring two j variables this way. Your solution is to not re-declare j in the loop, but rather declare it once as a long before the loop, or once as an int in the for loop initial condition (as you're doing). For instance you can try:

```
  long j = 3;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++, j++) {
     System.out.println(j);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

When you write:

```
long j;
for(int i=0, j=3;i<=10;i++,j++)
{
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

This is basically equivalent to:

```
long j;
int i = 0, j = 3;
while (i <= 10)
{
    System.out.println(j);
    i++, j++;
}
```

Essentially, you are attempting to create a new variable `j` of type `int` that is local to the loop. There is already a variable called `j` of type `long` defined, thus the error. You might omit the `long j;` declaration, or change it to `long j = 3;` to initialise it before the loop begins.

Answer (score 0):

either:

```
class Looping {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
      for(int i=0, j=3;i<=10;i++,j++) {
        System.out.println(j);
      }
    }
}
```

or:

```
class Looping {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
       long j=3;
       for(int i=0;i<=10;i++,j++) {
        System.out.println(j);
      }
    }
}
```

Explanation: the comma (,) after `int i=0`in your code example does not count as a statement separator, but effectively tells the compiler: `Define an integer i with value 0 AND a integer J with value 3`

Comment: ya now i got it. Thanks DOcJones

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0, j = 3; is the same thing as
int i = 0;
int j = 3;
```

So you're actually attempting to create another j variable.
I would suggest replacing the comma with a semicolon.